# JS based Diff/Patch for HTML/XML type content

Tags: javascript, patch

I've been working for a while on an application that has collaborative editing of plain text content. I have always had it on the back burner to add simple Rich Text support (namely bold, italic, underline, bulleted and numbered lists) but have not been able to find an algorithm that is written in JavaScript.

I know that the Google hosted diff-match-patch library has some suggestions for structured content, but I was hoping to find something that has already been written (yeah, I know, sounds lazy).

I have found one JS diff library, jsdifflib, but I'm unsure if it supports structured content (and it also doesn't have a patch library, which to me almost seems more important with structured content then the diff library, or is it?) DaisyDiff looks nice, but of course, there is no JS version.

Comment: I've been trying to think of ways to simplify things up. For one, I have thought about using some simple markup language instead of HTML, such as textile. I think it would help with things such as ordered lists, since there's no closing delimiter, but I assume the same problems could arise with bold, underline, italic.